# calcular porcentaje

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un problema a la hora de calcular el porcentaje tengo los siguientes campos: monto, porcentaje, ganancias mi problema es que el calculo lo hace mal, el campo porcentaje lo selecciono con un select y desde hay se procederá a sacar el calculo de porcentaje una vez ingresado el monto.

***anexo el código***

```
<script language="javascript">
 function multiplica(form){
 var resultado;
 var resultado2;
 var x=0;
 var y=0;
 x = parseInt (form.monto_trasferido.value);
 y = parseInt (form.id_porcentaje.value);

 resultado = x * y/100;
 form.ganancia.value=resultado;


  resultado2 = x + y;
  form.total.value=resultado2;

   }
  </script>
```

***los input y select***

```
   <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
   <input id="icon_prefix"  type="text" class="black-text" name="monto_trasferido" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, seleccione una fecha" pattern="[0-9]{5,7}" required/>
   <label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Monto Transferencia:</label>
   </div>



   <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
   <select name="id_porcentaje" id="id_porcentaje" class="browser-default" onblur="multiplica(this.form)" required/>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Porcentaje:</option>
   <?php
    $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM porcentaje ORDER BY id_porcentaje");
    while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $linea['id_porcentaje'] ;?>"><?php echo 
    $linea['porcentaje'] ;?>%</option>
    <?php
       }
     ?>
   </select>
   </div>


   <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
   <input id="icon_prefix"  type="text" class="black-text" name="ganancia"  readonly/>
   <label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Ganancia:</label>
   </div>


   <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
   <input id="icon_prefix"  type="text" class="black-text" name="total" autocomplete="off" required/>
   <label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Total:</label>
   </div>
```

***una imagen de muestra***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Su código en funcionamiento](https://repl.it/JXxg) claro con el cambio que mencionó @Matías en su respuesta

Comment: resultado =( x * y)/100; asi debe ir

Comment: el codigo en funionamiento funciona perfctamente pero tengo un problema cuando pongo los select sin ser cargados desde la bd funciona perfectamente, pero cuando os pongo cargado desde la bd me da el calculo mal

Comment: Porque el value del option debe ser el procentaje ($linea['porcentaje']) ya que es lo que utilizas para la operación, y no el identificador del procentaje ($linea['id_porcentaje']).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás sumando el `monto` que ingresa el usuario más el `número del porcentaje`, y lo que necesitas es sumar el `monto` más el resultado de calcular de `monto * porcentaje / 100`.

```
/*
* Devuelve la suma del monto más el porcentaje
* Monto = 1000
* Porcentaje = 50%
* Retorna 1050
*/
resultado2 = x + y;

/*
* Devuelve la suma del monto más el resultado de calcular el porcentaje sobre el monto
* Monto = 1000
* Porcentaje = 50%
* Retorna 1500
*/
resultado2 = x + resultado;
form.total.value = resultado2;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás haciendo mal la suma, se supone que tenes que sumar el monto mas el resultado de calcular monto * porcentaje /100